# How can I create an excerpt for each of a node's taxonomy terms?

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Rather than create a single node excerpt/ preview used across all Views for a taxonomy term, how can I create individual excerpts for a selection of taxonomy terms used to describe a node?

For example, if I have a node about a hotel that is family-friendly and has business facilities (both of which are also taxonomy terms), when I display a list of 'family-friendly' nodes I would like to display an excerpt with a short description of the family-friendly features of that hotel, whilst when displaying a list of nodes for hotels with 'business facilities', I would like to display excerpts with short descriptions of the business facilities at those hotels.

I've found the Excerpt module, but this only appears to provide a minor modification to how Drupal's existing excerpt feature works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting feature. I have never seen a  module which does it.

If you look at the [Open Calais](http://drupal.org/project/opencalais) module, you can see some custom extensions to the way taxonomy works. While it doesn't do what you want precisely it may be a  good guide for you.

In short, you can assign meta data to a node-term relationship which contains your excerpt. It would require a custom module and a fair amount of coding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, I don't have the capability to do any customisation and coding at the moment.

I think it's certainly a worthwhile future project, though. It would be an excellent extension of usability and SEO on a Drupal site.